# MongoDB - Counting number of occurrences per value using an index?

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to count, for each value, how many documents exist.

For example, my data may look like:

```js
[
    {"a": 5}
    {"a": 3}
    {"a": 5}
    {"a": 4}
]
```

and I have an index on the field "a".

I want the output:

```js
[
    {5: 2},
    {3: 1},
    {4: 1}
]
```

I can achieve this with an aggregation:

```js
db.table.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$a",
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

However, on millions of documents, this gets really really slow, as $group cannot use an index.

I have tried prefixing it with a $sort stage to force index use, so $group can use the sorted documents to be "faster", but the query is still taking a very very long time.

```js
db.table.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: {
            a: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$a",
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

From how I understand indexes, it should be relatively simple (if we had direct access to the index) to simulate this query.

Is there a way to do this specific query (document count per value) using an index, more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#improve-performance-with-indexes-and-document-filters), `$group` can only use an index to find the first document in each group, provided:

1. `$group` is preceded by `$sort` that sorts the field to group by, and
2. there is an index on the grouped field that matches the sort order, and
3. `$first` is the only accumulator in `$group`.

So, to calculate counts using an index is not possible. If this is some operation, that you need to perform frequently, I will recommend to store the output of your pipeline in some other collection, using `$merge` or `$out`, like this:

```
db.table.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$a",
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
   { $merge: { into: "groupedData", on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }
])
```

And then query this collection directly, and either run the above aggregation pipeline periodically, to update this new collection or modify your CRUD operations to do so.

Comment: Great solution. Unfortunately this still means it has to wait to get live data, or double my write throughput. Shame there's no way to directly query the index for the data it withholds from us!

Comment: Live data, is only possible, when the write operations to the table collection, and also update the counts in the grouped collection, which itself comes at the cost of more writes, but that's the tradeoff here one has to make.

Comment: Indeed, I was hoping someone would have a more efficient way to do it live.